# VBA Excel Linking value from Main Sub to its Called Function

Tags: function, excel, vba

I am still very new to vba in excel and is facing difficulties solving this problem..I really really hope someone could enlighten me where did my code went wrong and provide me with a solution as simplified as possible.  Thanks a lot& really appreciate it!

**Question:**
Loan applications are evaluated based on customer's income. 
We are supposed to use For-Next function and IF statements to show the following approval status:

Customer's income with respective status

> 60,000 Approve with special rates;  >40,000 Approve with standard rates; >24,000 Await manager's approval; Other cases  Reject application

Starting from row 2 in excel, Column B contains the "customer's income" figures and Column C in Excel contains the "loan application status" figures.

My code works well as follows:

```
Sub ForNext_If()

'CINCOME = Customer Income,Loan status= the application status, x = the row number, FinalRow= last row number 

x = 2
For x = 2 To 11 Step 1

CINCOME = Cells(x, 2).Value

If CINCOME > 60000 Then
LOANSTATUS = "Approve with special rates"

ElseIf CINCOME > 40000 Then
LOANSTATUS = "Approve with standard rates"

ElseIf CINCOME > 24000 Then
LOANSTATUS = "Await manager's approval"

Else
LOANSTATUS = "Reject application"

End If

Cells(x, 4) = LOANSTATUS

Next

End Sub
```

However, when I tried to use the call function,

```
Sub ForNext_If()

x = 2
For x = 2 To 11 Step 1

CINCOME = Cells(x, 2).Value

Call Calling

Cells(x, 4) = LOANSTATUS

Next

End Sub

Function Calling()

If CINCOME > 60000 Then
LOANSTATUS = "Approve with special rates"

ElseIf CINCOME > 40000 Then
LOANSTATUS = "Approve with standard rates"

ElseIf CINCOME > 24000 Then
LOANSTATUS = "Await manager's approval"

Else
LOANSTATUS = "Reject application"

End If

End Function
```

The CINCOME's value seemed not been able to transfer to the "Calling" function for it to determine a loan application status.T_T what exactly went wrong?

Comment: You have not supplied enough code bud. Please, explain what are CINCOME and LOANSTATUS. Just by looking at your procedure and function I can already tell they are not properly working. Think about specifying ranges for your CINCOME(customer income? + where i that variable declared? What i mean its like if CINCOME >= 24000 and CINCOME =< 40,000, If CINCOME > 40,000 and CINCOME < 60000, and if CINCOME > 60,000. What happens if income is less than 24,000? Maybe reconsider the use of VBA in this case - you may just as well use a simple formula to achieve your goal.

Comment: Sorry, regarding your problem - the value is not going to get 'transferred' to the Calling function because your not using any parameters.

Comment: Sorry, the CINCOME is Customer's Income and LOANSTATUS is the application status such as "Approve with special rates". Could you kindly explain what is parameters to 'transfer' the value to the Calling function? could you kindly give me an example? Thank you so much!

Comment: http://www.functionx.com/visualbasic/functions/Lesson2.htm

and i mean any tutorial on procedures, functions, or parameters will explain.

Comment: Thank you mehow!:) it has been a clearer picture to me now!:) However, I am required to use seperate routines using the IF statements and call these sub-routines (the IF statements) in my main routine too.. You mentioned about parameters, do you mind shedding me some light as well?:) thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to the comments. I have prepared two solutions for you ( there are more but these two are the first that came to my head ).

---

1. User Defined Function

    once the function is pasted in any of your modules, you can use it the worksheet by clicking cell and writing =LoanAppStatus(range), i.e. =LoanAppStatus(B2) + and you can drag this down your column

   ```
   ' User Defined Function
   ' Returns the status of customers loan application based on the income
   Function LoanAppStatus(CINCOME As Range) As String
       If CINCOME.Value >= 24000 And CINCOME.Value < 40000 Then
           LoanAppStatus = "Await manager's approval"

   ElseIf CINCOME.Value >= 40000 And CINCOME.Value < 60000 Then
       LoanAppStatus = "Approve with standard rates"

   ElseIf CINCOME.Value > 60000 Then
       LoanAppStatus = "Approve with special rates"

   Else
       LoanAppStatus = "Reject application"
   End If
   ```

   End Function

2. Rewrote your original sub procedure

```
'Procedure
' Fills the status of customers loan application (Column C) based on the income ( Column B )
    Sub ForNext_If()
        Dim i As Long
        Dim wS As Worksheet
        Set wS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        ' Range("B" & i).Value its what you called CINCOME
        ' Range("C" & i).Value its what you called LOANSTATUS

        With wS
          For i = 2 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If Range("B" & i).Value > 60000 Then
               Range("C" & i).Value = "Approve with special rates"
            ElseIf Range("B" & i).Value >= 40000 And Range("B" & i).Value < 60000 Then
               Range("C" & i).Value = "Approve with standard rates"
            ElseIf Range("B" & i).Value >= 24000 And Range("B" & i).Value < 40000 Then
               Range("C" & i).Value = "Await manager's approval"
            Else
               Range("C" & i).Value = "Reject application"
            End If
          Next i
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: where did your comment go? 
note: procedures do not return anything

Comment: Sorry i went to trial and error just now again and took a break from the comp. Thank you so much for your help mehow!:) Have managed to get it already:D Thanks!^_^